# Halide HelloAndroid import method not found

Tags: halide

I tried to import HelloAndroid project in Android Studio, but, when i try to build the apk and run it on a device, i get a gradle error:

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this and run the app?

Answer (score 1):

Original author of the build.gradle script here. As you can probably tell, our gradle build is pretty messy. It consists of three steps:

1. Build the Halide generators using gradle's native "cpp" plugin. That is, they're just regular C++ programs.
2. Run each Halide generator with per-architecture arguments to generate a set of .so files in the appropriate jni/libs/ directory.
3. Shell out to the ndk-build script to compile Android.mk, which links the JNI portion of the app with the Halide-generated .so files.

The process is brittle, especially with both Gradle and the Android platform changing under us. I've been waiting for the platform to stabilize with the new [Gradle Component Model that is still "incubating"](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/native_software.html) as well as the [New Android Build System](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system) and [New Experimental Plugin](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental).

In the meantime, everything should still build if you use Android Studio 1.5 and Gradle 1.2.2 (1.2.3 will probably work, but IIRC 1.2.4 is broken).

Comment: I built the native C++ portion of the script using the tutorial [here](https://gradle.org/getting-started-native/), which is quite out of date (Gradle 1.2.2 only, before they moved to the component model).

Comment: Once Android Studio 2.2 proper is released, I will see if it is possible to replace the Component Model with an [officially supported cmake based native build](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/external-c-builds).

Comment: I have another problem now. I read in the code that i need some includes, but the binary relsese i downloaded from the front page doesn't contain all the files it needs. For example: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\\workspace\\Halide-master\\apps\\HelloAndroid/../../bin.obj'
:linkHalide_generatorExecutable FAILED

Comment: I haven't seen that exact error but I think I know what the problem is. Depending on whether you downloaded the entire Halide tree from source or downloaded a binary distribution, and whether you compiled using Make or CMake, the Halide dependencies may be located in different paths.

It seems that your build failed on the first step - in linking to produce one of the generators. Look through build.gradle for instances of ${projectDir} and change them to what they should be. the "println" function should help you debug what the variables are.

Comment: Hello, may I know what is the highest version of Android Studio that supports the HelloCamera2? Is that example app still maintained? I am trying to use Halide in my Android App for fast image processing performance, but I don't know where to start other than those two demo apps. However, I am having trouble building those two demo apps